# Can bodies of equal volumes but slightly different mass float fully submerged in a liquid (may be at different depths)?

Tags: buoyancy, fluid-statics

Can bodies of equal volumes but slightly different mass (that is slightly different density) float (at rest) fully submerged in a liquid (may be at different depths)?

Consider - At different depths, buoyant force will be different.

Comment: Bouyant force is $\rho V g$, which doesn't depend on depth for liquids. This is because liquids are pretty much incompressible, so their density doesn't change with pressure. Gases, on the other hand, can have depth-dependent density.

Comment: @probably_someone Also, Buoyant force = (p2 - p1) A, where p2 is pressure at bottom of object (let cylinder) and p1 is pressure at top. AND this pressure difference depends on depth.

Comment: But $p=\rho g z$ at depth $z$ for liquids. Density is independent of depth for liquids, so $p_1-p_2=\rho g (z_1-z_2) $. Since $z_1-z_2$ is just the height of the object, we have that $(p_1-p_2)A=\rho g A (z_1-z_2)=\rho g V $, which is independent of depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both objects are fully submerged in an incompressible fluid (and liquids are essentially incompressible fluids), the buoyant force on both objects is

$$F_b=\rho_f g V $$

where $\rho_f $ is the density of the fluid, which is independent of depth for incompressible fluids. In other words, the buoyant force for fully submerged objects does not depend on depth.

Let both objects have the same volume $V$, but different masses $m_1$ and $m_2$. In order for both objects to float while fully submerged, the net force on both objects must be zero. Since the net force is the sum of gravity and the buoyant force, this amounts to equating these two forces:

$$\rho_f g V = m_1 g$$

$$\rho_f g V = m_2 g$$

But this also means that $m_1 g = m_2 g$, which in turn means $m_1=m_2$. Since we required that $m_1\neq m_2$,  this is impossible. Therefore, **it is impossible for both objects to float, fully submerged, in a liquid.** At least one of them will either sink to the bottom (at which point it is no longer floating) or float to the surface (at which point it is no longer fully submerged).

Answer (score 2):

The objects would indeed have different densities.

They could all float at different levels ***if*** the liquid had a density gradient, such that the density increased with depth.  Each sample would float at the level where the density of the liquid matched the density of the sample

A standard technique for measuring the density of small plastic samples is a density gradient column.  A low density liquid is carefully poured on top of a higher density, miscible liquid in a column. The interface is agitated so as to produce a smooth transition from one density to the other.  Samples of plastics of known density are dropped in, and settle to the appropriate level.

The known density samples can be used to determine the density of any unknown plastic dropped into the column.

Eventually the density gradient evens out, and the column needs to be drained and refilled...

See https://www.testingmachines.com/product/21-25-auto-density-measurement-system

Comment: If liquid don't have density gradient, then object with density equal to liquid will float (fully submerged) and others will sink or float at top. Am right?